# DataGrid locking up when scolling horizontally

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, active-directory

I have a `DataGrid` displaying a `List` of `UserPrincipals`. All is fine except for when I try to scroll horizontally. I can scroll about halfway through the columns, and then the program will lock up for 2-3 minutes before it allows scrolling again. After that, I can usually view the second half of the list, but it will lock up again if I scroll back to the first half.

#### XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="10,10,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          RenderTransformOrigin="2.25,-3.615" 
          MaxHeight="9001" MaxWidth="90000000"
          ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True}"/>
```

#### Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ActiveDirectorySearcher searcher;
    private ActiveDirectoryScope selectedScope;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new ActiveDirectoryScopeFetcher().Scope;
        InitializeComponent();
        selectedScope = null;
        DataGrid.EnableColumnVirtualization = true;
        DataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = true;
    }

    private void GetUsersButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedScope = TreeView.SelectedItem as ActiveDirectoryScope;
        Debug.WriteLine(selectedScope);
        if (selectedScope != null)
        {
            searcher = new ActiveDirectorySearcher
            {
                Scope = selectedScope
            };
            DataGrid.ItemsSource = searcher.GetUsers();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a scope.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `searcher.GetUsers()` method is returning a `List<UserPrincipal>`. It takes about three seconds to run, after which the `DataGrid` is populated. `ActiveDirectoryScope` and `ActiveDirectorySearcher` are two of my other classes that function as intended.

The freeze is consistently on the exact same column of the `DataGrid`. That makes me think that there is some set number of columns that the `DataGrid` loads at a time. However, all of the data must already be stored in memory, as memory usage does not increase during the freeze. CPU usage doesn't increase either.

I can scroll vertically without problems, and sorting by column is instantaneous. The only problem is with "loading" the second half of the columns in the display.